# Resolving a url as a different url inside kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes, alias, google-kubernetes-engine

My pod (pod1) internally can connect to another pod using its service like the following:

```
pod2-service.namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

However, I want `pod1` to connect to `pod2` using a URL like `abc.com` which is not registered in a DNS. Basically, I want pod1 to resolve `abc.com` as `pod2-service.namespace.svc.cluster.local`.

I was looking at `hostAliases` here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/.

However, it needs an IP. How can I do this in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a fixed ip as the service ip of your pod2, then use this ip in your hostalias definition.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things:

- [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) where you will always know the pod name and you can find it based on its [ordinal index](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#ordinal-index).
- [Using Pod hostname and subdomain spec field](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-hostname-and-subdomain-fields) (Only works for standalone pods, afaik)

However, pod to pod doesn't seem to be natively supported by Kubernetes in [Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), my guess the rationale here is that the pods can constantly change IP addresses and names. You could use [Pod default DNS entries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pods) but again the DNS entries will vary depending on the IP addresses that are assigned to pods.

The other solution that I can think of for Deployments is to use something like [Consul](https://www.consul.io/docs/platform/k8s/index.html) with [stub domains](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#configuration-of-stub-domain-and-upstream-nameserver-using-coredns), then on each pod you will have to add an [initContainer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) or consul agent sidecar to register its IP with the consul service, every time a pod restarts it will need to overwrite the DNS registration in Consul.

If you don't want to use stub domain there's also the option of using [Pod DNS Configs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-s-dns-config).

Answer (score 0):

you can get the service ip and append to `/etc/hosts` in pod1 before your application code running.

`echo "$(getent hosts pod2-service.namespace.svc.cluster.local | awk '{ print $1 }')  abc.com" >> /etc/hosts`

`Notice: It is pretty hacky because you should guarantee service ip of pod2 is fixed. When service ip changed, pod1 will fail to reslove the host.`